# Reload index.js in react after getting particular code for css from user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I want to reload my index.js file after the user selects a code from the dropdown for a particular CSS.
Say `arr=['red', 'green', 'yellow']` are the available options and the user selects any color, then I need to pick that config file and use it on my website.

PS.: I have other configurations too so can't just update the color, I need to fetch the file only after the user makes a request on ui.

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    document.write('<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/' +`${sessionStorage.getItem(CODE)}_${window['runConfig'].CSSFILE}` + '"><\/script>');
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: why reactjs is tagged?

Comment: how you pick your config file? for that small task you don't need react library